# I care for or about my life?

Tags: grammar

I'd like to know if it's I care for my life or about my life. Does anybody know which is the right answer? Or if both are correct?

Comment: Might be worth having a look at [this question on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122549/care-of-for-about-something-or-somebody).

Comment: Hello @Glenky! Please take a moment to take the [tour] and read our [help]. You need to provide your own research here, and clearly explain what you need help on.

Comment: Both are semantically correct but only the second one makes any sense. caring for your life would mean looking after your life, like caring for a sick person.

Comment: 'Care for' [a person] _in the relational sense_ (the other is to tend, nurse, look after) means 'hold in one's affections', 'like quite deeply'. 'Care about' _can_ have a largely overlapping sense, with more of a hint of a concern for welfare, but here it has the 'be concerned about; regard and treat [the environment, the NHS, someone's life ...] as very important' sense and is the correct choice. Probably an ELL question.

Comment: @Alan *I care for my life—I eat healthy food and exercise daily.* That makes complete sense to me.

Comment: @Jason, in think you're right, although I'd have thought it / said it with "health" rather than "life", but the fact the substitution works for me means you're correct